# How can I see what request is done by Ember FastBoot?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've installed `ember-cli-fastboot` and a certain path throws an `Error: The adapter operation was aborted` server-side (i.e. in the terminal).

Can I output all requests FastBoot does, so I can see what the last one was before the rendering of the page was aborted due to this error message?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can connect FastBoot to Chrome DevTools and see all network requests from the Network tab.

Here are the instructions:

https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot#developer-tools

Comment: This sounds perfect, but using inspect crashes my app in the starting phase. _"Dang! Looks like a Build Error."_ `ember-cli-fastboot/instance-initializers/clear-double-boot.js` - _Worker terminated unexpectedly_ when running e.g. `node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9230 node_modules/.bin/ember s --environment=development`

Comment: Asked about this here: https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot/issues/645